# Creating matrix from characteristic poynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How can we create a matrix from the characteristic polynomial? I know the procedure for creating the same when there are no repeated roots.

The procedure I used was to create a diagonal matrix  with each of the factors of the polynomial as the diagonal elements. For e.g. Characteristic polynomial of $ \lambda^2 $- 1 = 0 will give a matrix with $ \lambda -1 $ and $ \lambda + 1 $ as the diagonal elements. But how do we solve it for a characteristic polynomial with repeated roots like $ (\lambda - 2)^2 $     $ \lambda^2 - 1 $= 0

I could repeat the same procedure and the resulting diagonal matrix will have two identical elements namely $ \lambda - 2 $ but that I believe is incorrect. Please help

Comment: You may be looking for the "companion matrix", see, e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix

Answer (score 0):

As it is phrased, you have answered your own question (although your writing is very unclean. If the characteristic polynomial is $\chi(\lambda)=\lambda^2-1$, then we do not have a matrix with $\lambda\pm 1$ on the diagonal but rather $\pm 1$). You can repeat your procedure and (in the setting of your example) obtain a matrix with two identical elements on the diagonal. As you can easily verify, the characteristic polynomial is indeed as stated (here, I assume the polynomial is $\chi(\lambda)=(\lambda-2)^2(\lambda^2-1)$ rather than the one you stated).

However, I believe that this is not really what you were looking for. What you rather seem to have in mind is the question of all different matrices that have the given polynomial as characteristic polynomial (up to conjugacy). Now for a characteristic polynomial without multiplicities, there is - up to conjugacy - only one matrix with this characteristic polynomial, while if the characteristic polynomial has multiplicities, there are several. Let's do an example:
\begin{align*}
 A:=\begin{pmatrix}{} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad B:=\begin{pmatrix}{} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} 
\end{align*}
both have characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(\lambda)=\chi_B(\lambda)=(\lambda-1)^2$ (however, their minimal polynomials differ).
The reason is, if you so wish, that the characteristic polynomial does not separate orbits of the conjugacy operation of $GL(n)$ on the $n\times n$ matrices.

To answer the extended question, you can have a look at the Jordan normal form (or the corresponding result for arbitrary fields).